# Cannot write to windows share ntfs folder from mac

Tags: windows-7, mac, file-sharing

I have a windows 7 shared folder, I can connect to windows 7 using smb protocol and can mount the drive on mac. I can get files from that shared folder but how to write/paste files from my mac to windows7's shared folder?

Or I need to format the volumne to some other type in order to get the write access? I dont want to use FAT32 as I have some files larger than 4GB

Comment: What does the permissions scheme look like on the share? Does the user that is connecting via the Mac actually have write permissions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you created the shared folder on Windows, you had the opportunity to change the default permissions on the share (which grants **Everyone** read-only access).  You should go back to the share properties, and click on **Permissions** and grant **Full Control** permission to one or more *Windows* users known to your machine.  Or you can give **Everyone** Full Control (but be careful what data you expose).

When you access the share from another machine (even a Mac) you should be required to authenticate with the Windows machine, at which time you would enter a username/password for a user known to the Windows machine. Then you will have write access.

Comment: I'm connecting as my admin user, which has full access rights to drive S:, and yet the volume is still read-only from OS X.

Comment: I found that it helped to connect to the SMB URL `smb://myusername@myserver/mysharename`  - here's [how to connect to an SMB URL with Finder](http://users.wfu.edu/yipcw/atg/apple/smb/) -  the key is to ensure you are connecting as the Windows user expected.  I believe sometimes you can end up connecting as a guest user on Windows with read-only access.

Answer (score 4):

The underlying volume format won't matter for SMB shares. It's definitely a permissions issue. Keep in mind that share permissions are separate from disk permissions set on files and folders.  You can try setting up [simple file sharing](http://www.home-network-help.com/file-sharing-in-windows-7.html) on your Win7 machine.  Or if you're using password protected sharing, then the easiest thing to do will be to create a user account on you Win7 machine with the same logon name and password as your OS X user and make sure the user account has permissions to the share and folder.

Comment: +1 for the info "The underlying volume format won't matter for SMB shares"

Answer (score 0):

On windows (server side) edit the share settings, its likely everyone has read access but the share setting does not include write access for a user / group. Just right click folder and edit sharing>advanced.